# Link to ISO doc? Complexity of unordered_map operations in C++::stl

Tags: c++, algorithms, stl

In different forums, I have found the statement that in C++::stl, insert and find for unordered_map have guaranteed amortized time complexity O(1). This puzzles me, and I would like to see the official document (perhaps ISO) to see exactly what is being demanded. Could someone provide me with the link?

Here is why I think that guaranteed time complexity amortized O(1) may not be possible. Please correct me if I say something wrong, as I am not an experienced programmer. The best way to implement an unordered map is through the use of a hash table. It seems reasonable towant to use keys that are strings of length at most 1000. Let's assume that the alphabet has size 26. Then we are possibly dealing with more than 26^1000 different strings. Any hash function would need to give an array index ranging over 2^64 possible indices. However, any hash function from a set of size 26^1000 to a set of size 2^64 must result in at least one array index having more than exp(600) strings that  all hash to that same array index. So, unless there is some special information about the special nature of the strings to be hashed, one cannot choose a hash function that is guaranteed to work for a chained hash table. For an open hash table, with probes, my argument is not complete, but it seems to be enough to make one worry about guarantees.

Given a specific hashing scheme (not necessarily one found in a textbook), is it possible to choose a sequence of strings (all of length 1000) such that the time to insert increases linearly with the number of strings?

Comment: "Link to the ISO doc?", programmers.SE is not "let me google that for you".  However, I obliged you and included the link in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks very much for doing the Googling. I did try to do this myself, but couldn't find the appropriate document.

Answer (score 2):

Hash tables are fairly complicated data structures, and depending on how you implement them performance will vary. Also, some implementations can easily be tricked to enter a worst case. No matter how you implement a hash table, the worst case for insertion and retrieval will be `O(n)`. However, hash tables still have very attractive complexity for the *average* case, especially when using chaining for collision resolution which I will analyze in the rest of this answer.

First, a bit of terminology. A hash table consists of `k` buckets (storage locations) and contains `n` key-value pairs. We can now calculate the *load factor* `f = n/k`. This load factor also approximately (for small `f`) corresponds to the probability that when we insert an element, the addressed bucket is already in use.<sup>[1]</sup> The load factor `f` is also the expected number of elements in a bucket! Therefore, retrieval for a hash table is not `O(1)` but really `O(f)` on average – the worst case `O(n)` still holds.

<sup>[1]: To be precise, the probability of at least one collision upon insertion of an element is `pc = 1 - (1 - 1/k)n` due to the birthday paradox.</sup>

To be really pedantic, the average case is `O(f) = O(n/k) = O(n)` for a fixed `k`. This is bad, since it defeats the whole point of using a hash table. Therefore, implementations use *dynamic resizing* to limit the load factor to some constant value, typically `fmax = 0.7 ± 0.1`. Whenever our load factor reaches that limit, we reallocate the hash table to double that size `k`, which also halves the load factor! Each reallocation is `O(n)`, but it only happens every `1/n` insertions. So while each individual insertion can take up to `O(n)`, the cost spread out over all insertion is `O(1)` – the *amortized* complexity. It is therefore correct to say that a hash table with chaining and dynamic resizing has `O(1)` amortized complexity in the average case for insertion and retrieval.

There are still some assumptions here: the hash function must be uniform (that is, must use its entire codomain with roughly equal probability), and must have negligible cost. For variable-sized key types, this might not be given, so that it would be more correct to state that insertion and retrieval is `O(h(key))`. However, this complexity is independent from the data structure but rather a property of the data, so that we should (mostly) ignore it when analyzing the data structure.

Your argument is based on the *pigeonhole principle* and is correct, but not meaningful.

> So, unless there is some special information about the special nature of the strings to be hashed, one cannot choose a hash function that is guaranteed to work for a chained hash table.

Any hash function that fulfils certain properties will work. In fact, since the hash function is used to derive a bucket index, it does not have a codomain of size `264` but actually only of size `k`. However, hash collisions are expected and can be resolved in a manner that maintains the `O(1)` complexity. To resolve a hash collision, the un-hashed key is stored along with the value in the bucket. Upon retrieval, the retrieval key is compared with the stored key for equality. If a bucket contains more than one entry, we compare against all stored keys. This is effectively a linear search, but as shown above it is `O(1)` on average when using dynamic resizing, and it correctly handles hash collisions.

> Given a specific hashing scheme […], is it possible to choose a sequence of strings […] such that the time to insert increases linearly with the number of strings?

Yes, if we trigger the worst case such that all strings have the same hash. E.g. when [using `strlen()` as a hash function](http://news.php.net/php.internals/70691) (which is not advisable since its not an uniform hash on most data), then using lots of strings of the same length as keys in the table will all map to the same bucket, regardless of the size of the hash table. Since this could be used in denial-of-service attacks, some hash table implementations use randomized hash functions where the worst case cannot be predicted by an attacker. This is not possible in C++, but the `std::unordered_map` allows you to provide a custom hash function as a template parameter if you are aware of certain properties of your keys.

But again, this is only the worst case. As mentioned above the discussion of average complexity assumes that the hash function is in fact uniform.

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Overflow explains the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15470948/c-unordered-map-complexity) in a way that might help you understand why the standard just says "it is so". The [proposal discusses it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1456.html) in slightly mroe detail (search for 'compexity').

> **Control of Hash Resizing**
>
> The time required for looking up an element by key k is c1 + c2 n,
>   where c1 and c2 are constants, and where n is the number of elements
>   in the bucket indexed by k's hash code. If the hash function is well
>   chosen, and elements are evenly distributed between buckets, this is
>   approximately c1 + c2 N/B, where N is the number of elements in the
>   container and B is the bucket count. If the bucket count is taken as a
>   constant, then the asymptotic complexity for element lookup is O(N).
>
> To maintain average case complexity O(1) for lookup, the bucket count
>   must grow as elements are added to the hash table; on average the
>   bucket count must be proportional to N. Another way of putting this is
>   that the load factor, N/B, must be approximately constant.
>   ...

Your second question is easy, any hashing scheme that returns the same constant every time will require a bucket insert every time, and with a linear-time insert (via choice of bucket scheme) you get linear time.

Answer (score 0):

[Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/)<sup>*</sup> states the following about [`std::undered_map::operator[]` § Complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/operator%5B%5D/#complexity):

> Average case: constant.
>
> Worst case: linear in container size.
>
> May trigger a rehash if an element is inserted (not included in the complexity above).

It states that on **average** the complexity is *O(1)*; but in worst case as with your identifiers constructed to generate colliding hashes the performance might be linear as you reasoned yourself.

In addition when [`reserving`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/reserve/) more space than [`bucket_count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/unordered_map::bucket_count)`*`[`max_load_factor`](http://www.cplusplus.com/unordered_map::max_load_factor) a [`rehash`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/rehash/) is triggered.  `insert` and `map["key"] = value` may also trigger a rehash.  The [rehash'es complexity](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/rehash/#complexity) is:

> In case of rehash,
>
> Average case: linear in container size.
>
> Worst case: quadratic in container size.

## TLDR

The OP is correct about the complexity. The standard states this, the OP has overlooked it.  Yes it is possible to construct a sequence of keys that would generate terrible performance; [security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) may have something useful to say about that.

This is the link to [International C++ standard - n3242.pdf](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) (i.e. [ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards#14882))

---

<sup>*) I'm not sure if [Cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) is the canonical reference for [ISO/IEC 14882:2011](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/standards#14882) but they appear to follow it quite closesly</sup>